# Update "Simple" Listbox ZK

Tags: listbox, zk

I want to update the listbox when submit button is clicked. the listbox initially consists of a list of JSONObject, after submit button clicked, the list elements changed and the listbox should update with the change but I can't do this. can you help me upadate the listbox?

this is how I put the list of JSONObject in the listbox

```
<listbox id="userListbox">
<listhead>
    <listheader label="Id"></listheader>
    <listheader label="Name"></listheader>
    <listheader label="Address"></listheader>
    <listheader label="Phone"></listheader>
</listhead>
<listitem forEach="${userController.list}">
    <listcell label="${each.id}" ></listcell>
    <listcell label="${each.name}" ></listcell>
    <listcell label="${each.address}" ></listcell>
    <listcell label="${each.phone}" ></listcell>
</listitem>
```

in class UserController:

```
private List<JSONObject> list;

@Listen("onClick = #submitButton")
public void onSubmit(Event event) {
    loadUser();
}

private void loadUser() {
    JSONObject input = new JSONObject();
    input.put("name", nameBox.getText());

    list = getUserList(input);
}

public List<JSONObject> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<JSONObject> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

and I don't know how to update the listbox? thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in class UserController:

```
private List<JSONObject> list;
Listbox userListbox;
@Listen("onClick = #submitButton")
public void onSubmit(Event event) {
    loadUser();
}

private void loadUser() {
    JSONObject input = new JSONObject();
    input.put("name", nameBox.getText());

    list = getUserList(input);
    userListbox.setModel(list);
    userListbox.set//Your own item renderer
}

public List<JSONObject> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<JSONObject> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

and I don't know how to update the listbox? thank you for your help.

Comment: thanks for your help. since I am new in ZK, should I create class renderer or not? in the first code (.zul file) I just put the list and call each key in JSONObject without any renderers. do I have to create class renderer to update the listbox?

Comment: yes you should create a class Renderer which implements ListitemRenderer and override method getListitem(),setRenderer only once to your Listbox next time when your list(data) changes you only have to do listbox.setModel().